# Hosting Google VM on web

Tags: web-server, virtual-machines, web-hosting, google-app-engine, flask

sorry for the rookie question, I'm just starting with Google Cloud and web developement. I have a Flask application, works perfectly locally, and also when deployed to a VM in GC. However I can only trigger the API now by using the external IP address, and I'd like to give it a friendly url.

So currently I have 15.15.15.15/triggerawesomapi
And I want to have: https://awesomeapplication.com/triggerawesomapi

What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: create a dns record point to that ip

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) The easier and faster way, but less reliable:

```
1.1. Assign an external/static IP to your VM server
1.2. Change your DNS entry awesomeapplication.com to point to your static external IP

In this case, your application is supposed to have an outage in case your server goes down
```

Option 2) Demands a little more work, but it's more reliable

```
2.1. Create a VM image with your application
2.2. Create a MIG (Managed Instance Group)
2.3. Configure a load balancer with health-check pointing to your MIG
2.4. Change your DNS entry to point to your load balancer

In this case, GCP is supposed to launch a new healthy VM, in case of an application failure
```

Option 3) Recommended one: Easier to maintain e reliable

```
3.1. Create a docker image and deploy it to AppEngine
3.2. Change your DNS entry to point to your AppEngine's URL

In this case, you're supposed to have automatic scale and reliability. Besides, AppEngine standard can downscale to zero when idle, in order to save costs. In addition, you can leverage canary deployments and cache from default's AppEngine infrastructure.
```